# Eclipse does not ask what android device to use

Tags: android

I am implementing an Android app and I need to test on the emulator and the phone. But when I run the app it runs on the phone without asking me or showing me the option on what do i want to test my app. Can somebody help me how to acheive this.thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the "Run" menu at the top, and select "Run Configurations...". On the left, under "Android Application", select your project. Select the "Target" tab, and select "Always prompt to pick device". Then click "Run" at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Related tip -- After telling it to always use a certain device (checkbox on the pop-up dialog), the said option wouldn't let me switch devices. I worked around it by duplicating my run configuration.

Comment: @JohnLehmann Weird... I've never encountered that. Hope it helps someone else in the future, though!

Comment: @JohnLehmann, you should submit this as an answer. This Eclipse bug (?) was driving me crazy. Your workaround is a good one.

Comment: @Jonathan, I believe it is an answer. :)  If you mean submit as an Eclipse bug, please do that.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project > properties > run/debug settings >  > Edit configuration properties

Here you will be able to select the android device as well as choose other options which you can use to run your android application

You can select different targets from the target tab.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

If you have checked "Use same device for future launches" in chooser dialog, you must disconnect all devices (usb and simulators) and then click in "run" again and uncheck the checkbox!